# Detect swipe gesture in webbrowser

Tags: codenameone

I have a Codename One app that contains a web browser view to a mobile friendly site. I can't change the code on the site itself so need to do anything from the Java side only. I need to include a method for going back a page.

The client would prefer swipe to go back on iOS like Safari has, however the webbrowser component doesn't pass touch events back to the Java code.

I need a way to detect the swipe gesture on the web browser and handle it in the Java code. I think perhaps the Javascript interop features would help but I'm not sure how to manage this without making changes to the website code, which I am unable to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BrowserComponent` includes the ability to inject JavaScript code into a website in the `onLoad` event. There are some samples of this here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/package-summary.html

You can inject JavaScript into the site after it loaded and then do the swipe back listening in JavaScript. It's a bit of work though, I'd just add a back arrow to the top as the swipe back is iOS specific and won't be intuitive to users of other platforms.